# javascript open window url on exit

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to open a new URL on page exit in a browser window using javacript. My goal is when user closes the window to see the javascript alert box and when he press "Leave this Page" Instead ot the browser window to be closed to be redirected to google.com.

my code so far is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var areYouReallySure = false;
    var internalLink = false;
        function areYouSure() {
            if (!areYouReallySure && !internalLink) {
            areYouReallySure = true;
            location.href="http://www.google.com"
            return "Do you wish to go to google?";
        }
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;

    $('a').click(function(){
    internalLink = true;
    });
});
</script>
```

Rigth now when I chose leave this page it only closes the window.

Comment: When a user leaves the page, you don't get to decide where they go from there.

Comment: I hope no one answers you  :-) I have the feeling a lot of bad guys want to know the answer to your question

Comment: The only reasonable use case for this is to check that a user has saved data and, even then, I'd argue it's not necessary and goes against reasonable usability expectations. If a user wishes to leave your page or go somewhere else, then that's up to them. They don't want annoying prompts asking them to stay where they are or to interject some other URL to them. The user expects to have that choice themselves.

Comment: "Rigth now when I chose leave this page it only closes the window." Thanks God

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible, and with good reason. Imagine if spam sites controlled what happens when you close their page. As a security measure, the only thing you can do when a user tries to navigate away from your page is display a message. This was implemented mostly so users can be warned that they haven't saved their data.